# How to change font Awesome plus to minus using j Query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plus font Awesome icon i want to change it into minus when user clicks on plus and vice versa

I am using it in my HTML table to expand some rows

```js
$('i').click(function() {

  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-plus fas fa-minus');
});
```

```css
.icon {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<i class="fas fa-plus icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row1"></i>
```

Comment: this is the `i` element that has been clicked so you do not need the `find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use find `$this` represent `i`, and toggle multi pal class to change `class` and shape like below.

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus green fa-minus red');
});
```

```css
.icon {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.green{
color: green;
}
.red{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<i class="fas fa-plus icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row1"></i>
```

Comment: hey I have tried to use your code but that is not working can you please checkout this link https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/2h7vkgj4/1/

Comment: I have commented the line where i think it is causing issue, it is at bottom of my Java-Script code

Comment: I found your problem. You reset your table after 1 second using setTimeout. Increase the number fix the problem . See working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7mdxhuf4/

Comment: @hey that ain't working, as i am setting dynamic `height` by this `var $winHeight = $(window).height();
    var $bodyHeight = $winHeight - 320;` so here in fiddle the height is less than the table height make that height `500px` and check it is not working

Comment: please check out https://jsbin.com/ceyazejade/edit?js,output  i am using `isdrawtable` to fix my scroll issue which is coming again when i am setting timeout more than 100

Comment: I dont under stand what you mean ?

Comment: look be it 100 and run and on click of  `Bakery FG`  scroll from left side it will scroll fine, but when you increase the setTimeout then it scrolls alone

Comment: I think problem is "scrollCollapse": true, . Check once to comment this line.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, but your selector is incorrect (you can just use `$(this)` inside of an event handler to reference the clicked element):

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  var color = ($(this).hasClass('fa-minus')) ? 'red' : 'green';
  $(this).css('color', color);
});
```

```css
.icon {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<i class="fas fa-plus icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row1"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove find() and it will be work.

```js
$('i').click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  $(this).hasClass('fa-minus')? $(this).css('color','red'): $(this).css('color','green');
});
```

```css
.icon {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<i class="fas fa-plus icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row1"></i>
```